# Creating erlang record from two separate lists

Tags: mysql, erlang

In one of our erlang project we are loading data from mysql database using mysql-otp as below -

```
{ok, Columns, Rows} = mysql:query(ConnectionPid, <<"SELECT * FROM credentials WHERE username = ?">>, [Username])
```

Now `Columns` is a list of binaries consisting all column names and `Rows` are the list of list of records.

For eg.

```
Columns = [<<"id">>, <<"username">>, <<"password">>, <<"is_active">>]
Rows = [[1,"test_user_1", "password", 'Y'], [2, "test_user_2", "password", 'Y']]
```

Now we would like to cache the mysql records into ets tables on load. So we will need to create the records from the above two lists.

For eg. we have the below record declaration

```
-record(credentials, {id, username, password, is_active}).
```

So how to create the list of `credentials` record from the above two list `Columns` and `Rows`. Any idea?

> Edits

we can't use `list_to_tuple` function as there might be variable number of elements in the `Rows` list than `credentials`

Comment: You can not make records in runtime, they are created in compile time. Use maps instead.

Comment: If you have the record definition `credentials`, then the Columns list is irrelevant, so your question is very poorly asked.

Comment: @7stud I hope u didn't get my question. Anyways I have solved it in my way and it's working fine.

Comment: @Neel: If you solved it, please post the answer here for others to know.

Answer (score 0):

If your data in `Rows` is consistent in the way that the values in `[Id,Username,Password,IsActive|_]` can always be expected to be orderly and other extra values will be tailing them, you won't need `Columns` as mentioned by @7stud in the post's comments.

Here is how I'd do with list comprehension:

```
Creds = [ #credentials{
                 id=Id,
                 username=Usr,
                 password=Pw,
                 is_active=Act} || [Id,Usr,Pw,Act|_] <- Rows ]
```

The `_` means that we ignore whatever extra values there might be that won't fit into `credentials`'s shape.

Answer (score 0):

As @Pouriya mentioned records are compiled. I would use maps and list comprehension. Columns or Rows can be replaced by your mysql results. (Ps: haven't tested this for performance!)

```
-module(lc).
-export([start/0]).

start() ->
    Columns = ["id", "firstname", "lastname", "prefix", "initials", "birthday"],
    Rows = [
                [82, "Bob", "Dubalina", "", "B.", {1971,1,29}],
                [45, "Alice", "Wonderland", "", "A.", {1975,2,14}],
                [23, "John", "Doe", "", "J.", {1982,5,5}],
                [72, "Jane", "Doe", "", "J.", {1995,7,17}]
            ],
    Data = #{ "data" =>    [ 
                            maps:from_list([ {lists:nth(X, Columns) , lists:nth(X, Values)} || X <- lists:seq(1, length(Columns))])
                        || Values <- Rows ] 
            },
    Data.
```